# Order by CASE with duplicate values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table "tbl_matches"

```
  NAME     START_DATE         STATUS
  John     2018-08-1 08:30    Prematch
  Paul     2018-08-1 05:30    Prematch
  Sam      2018-08-1 05:30    Prematch
  Mel      2018-08-1 05:30    Live
```

Here's my query

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_matches
ORDER BY CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Live' THEN true ELSE NULL DESC
```

What I want is to move "Mel" record **above Paul**, just between Paul and John, because Mel status has **Live** and also it has the **same date and time** with Paul and Sam.

The logic should be:  If the status is "Live" then move the record above other records has the same "Date and Time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_matches
ORDER BY START_DATE, CASE WHEN STATUS ='Live' THEN '0' ELSE '1' END;
```

`CASE` will assign the value `0` where `Status` is **Live** otherwise it will assign `1`. Then `ORDER BY` will sort it in `Ascending` order by default

Answer (score 2):

just use `case when` for status column and put START_DATE also in order by clause

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_matches    
order by START_DATE,case when status ='Live' then 0 else 1 end
```